# Code calls new GenericObject() but GenericObject.java doesn't have a constructor

Tags: java, compiler-construction, constructor

I'm looking through some code that I'm working with and one bit of it strikes me in particular:

In the file there is a block:

```
public void prepare(){
    if (this.GenericObjectID != null) 
         doStuff();
    else{
         this.GenericObjet = new GenericObject();
    }
```

However, when I look through `GenericObject.java` there is no constructor at all. The code runs, but I didn't write it, so I'm not positive how (yet!). So my question is: how is this possible? What is the java compiler doing when it sees this call but then no constructor in the file that describes the object?

Comment: If you haven't defined any constructor then compiler by default add one for you. `public GenericObject(){}`

Comment: This must be a duplicate of some question, but of course searching for "java default constructor" only finds questions with that in the title. Can someone more familiar with the Java tag find a dupe to point this at?

Comment: I felt the same way, but couldn't find anything. Of course, before the two answers below and comment above I didn't even know what I was searching for ;)

Comment: @amalloy I'd like to have, somewhere, a list of common "canonical questions" for basic Java questions.  I've run into other cases where I'm sure questions have been asked multiple times but I can't find a good question.  I'd try doing this myself, if only I had time ... sigh :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are no explicit constructors, then the compiler creates an implicit *default constructor*, with no arguments, that does nothing but implicitly call the superclass constructor.

[Section 8.8.9 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) talks about default constructors:

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared. The form of the default constructor for a top level class, member class, or local class is as follows:
>
> - The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class (§6.6).
> - The default constructor has no formal parameters, except in a non-private inner member class, where the default constructor implicitly declares one formal parameter representing the immediately enclosing instance of the class (§8.8.1, §15.9.2, §15.9.3).
> - The default constructor has no throws clauses.
> - If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.

Comment: huh, interesting about the "non-private" bit for inner classes! Any idea what that exemption is doing there? javap shows that a private ctor with the one parameter _does_ exist: https://gist.github.com/yshavit/9cd954b1c01b0f5d27cc

Comment: @yshavit I don't know why "non-private" is there.  I would upvote that question if you post it as a separate question.

Comment: I may vote to close my own question as "primarily opinion based," I think, unless we happen to hear from [someone with actual cred](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz). :-\ Plus I have such a questionless track record! (In seriousness, I still don't know whether "why" questions are ok here.)

Comment: @yshavit I've seen many "Why did the language designers do it this way?"-like questions rightfully closed as primarily opinion based, but for all I know, either there's a technical reason, or that is a JLS error -- not opinion based (in my opinion!).

Answer (score 2):

`new GenericObject();` is the default constructor for the class `GenericObject`. It is automatically created by the compiler unless you explicitly define a constructor in your class.

This constructor will call the parent class' constructor, and will initialize class member variables to their default values.

Comment: Clarification: that last should be "unless you explicitly define _any_ constructor in your class".  If you define a constructor with two arguments, the compiler will **not** define a default no-argument constructor.